# How can i link a user input to a string

Tags: c#

i have this code

```
        string F1 = "text file";
        string F2 = "document";
        string F3 = "doc2";
        Console.WriteLine("What file do you want to open? \nF1. Text File \nF2. Document \nF3. Doc2");
        string whatfile = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(whatfile, out int filenum) == true)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start($"d:/files/{whatfile.Trim().ToLower()}.txt");
        }
```

What i want to do here is when the user says something it checks if its a number, if it is then it would open the corresponding file. But i want to do this without anymore if statements. Is it possible to have each file name linked to a variable (like `F1`) and then link `whatfile` input to it too, and if the user said `F1`  it would call the string. On a side note, is there anyway if a user tries to open a non-existing file, then instead of having the app crash have it do something like `Console.WriteLine("Invalid File");`? (Note: the code for opening the file using numbers will, obviously, go into the empty `if` statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want some kind of mapping between the names and the file-paths. You can use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> filePaths = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    { "F1", "text-file-path" }, { "F2", "doc1-path" }, { "F3", "doc2-path" }
};

Console.WriteLine("What file do you want to open? \nF1. Text File \nF2. Document \nF3. Doc2");
string whatfile = Console.ReadLine();
if (filePaths.TryGetValue(whatfile, out string file))
{
    Console.WriteLine("File Opened: " + file);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid File");
}
```

I have passed `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to the dictionary constructor just to show you how you can compare in a case insensitive way. If you don't want that simply omit the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't just open the file. First check if it exists:

```
if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName))
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid File");
else
{
    //Do the opening
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly :

- first you have to collect all the files from a folder right ?
  `string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\")`
- second imagine you want to open the second file

````
int value;
if (int.TryParse(line, out value)) // check if the input is an int
{
if(File.Exist(files[int.Parse(line)])
 // Open the file
else
Console.WriteLine("File not found");
}```

I hope that's help you ^^'
````